# Runtime exceeded when reading cin but not when reading from file?

Tags: c++, file, input, io, runtime

So I have written a program that runs as intended when taking input from a file, but throws a "runtime exceeded" error (I'm using onlinegdb). The input in both cases is separated like so:

````
```
input
```
````

I copied this into a text file and it worked, but entering the input as standard input at the bottom of the screen does not work. I can also input to console, which also works fine. My readFromFile function is the same function but with file I/O functions instead of cin. This is my first time really experimenting with input/output. Please help!!

````
   void readFromInput() {
     string Word;
     int count = 0;
     while (cin >> Word) {
       if (Word == "```") {
           count++;
       }
       if (count == 2) {break;} //exit after recieving opening and closing ```
       if (Word == "Add") {
         //do stuff
       }
       if (Word == "Charge") {
         //do stuff
       }
       if (Word == "Credit") {
         //do stuff
       }
     }
     return;
   }
````

Comment: What is the difference between "input to console" and "entering the input as standard input" in your testing? Is one of them labeled "Interactive Console" and the other labeled "Text" at [onlinegdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com/)? Your code works fine in both cases when I try it. See [this](https://onlinegdb.com/BJ3XGFlcQ).

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of special features of the standard input/output that don't apply to normal file streams:

The C++ `std::cin` and `std::cout` is linked to the C streams by default. To keep these in sync is expensive. If you are not using C streams this is not necessary. To remove this cost unlink them:

```
int main()
{
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
}
```

If your code uses input and output streams. Reading from `std::cin` forces `std::cout` to be flushed (to make sure user questions reflect the input question). This can be inefficient if the two are not linked. So untie them,

```
int main()
{
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
}
```

Prefer to use `'\n'` over `std::endl` to avoid extra flushes.